# How to upload multiple photos in a picture library to Word or PPT in SharePoint 2013? This worked using Actions | Send To in SP2010

Tags: file-upload, office

In the photo library in SP2010, under Actions, you can select multiple photos and choose “send to” Word, Excel, PPT, etc.  There’s no Actions drop down in SP2013.

Here’s an article that describes the functionality in SP2010.

https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Work-with-photos-in-a-picture-library-f32a65a4-a525-492d-a789-dbe3186120cb

***To include the files in an Outlook message, Word document, PowerPoint presentation, or Excel file Excel worksheet, click Send pictures to.***

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your goal is it insert pictures saved in a SharePoint picture library into a PowerPoint presentation, Word document, or as email attachments.  To do that:

1. In Windows, create a network location to the SharePoint picture library.
2. Once the network location is created, open the desired Office application.
3. In Word (PowerPoint, Outlook, etc.) click the Insert tab, then click Pictures, and finally in the dialogue box navigate to your computer/PC network locations.
4. Select the picture library and insert the image(s) into your Word document.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is removed from 2013. Instead you can use the Share feature to share files among your colleagues.

Also from content management point of view there is no point in sending document as file attachments. I believe that is the reason this feature got replaced with Share feature.